# Python SMTP - Receive email in Sent Items after email is sent to user

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I'm sending an email to a list of users stored in a csv file.

I've tested it multiple times and the emails are sent and received.

However, I would like to see the eamils that have been sent in my 'Sent Items' folder in Outlook.

It doesn't seem possible to do this with Python SMTP..
Is there an "easy" way to achieve this please ?

Here is the sample code:

```
def emailHtmlToUser(email, userToClean):
    sender = emailCleanupSenderAddress
    receiver = email

    Details = ""
    for row in userToClean:
        url = "http://www.website.com/home/item.html?id="+row["ItemID"]
        Details += "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>".format(row["Title"], url)

    fp = open(emailCleanupHtmlModelPath, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read().format(mapsDetails), 'html')
    fp.close()

    msg['Subject'] = emailCleanupSubject
    msg['From'] = emailCleanupSenderName
    msg['To'] = receiver

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, [receiver], msg.as_string())
        smtpObj.quit()
        log("Email (HTML) sent successfully to : {0}".format(email))
    except Exception:#SMTPException:
        log("Error: unable to send email to : {0}".format(email))

    return
```

Answer (score -1):

In awork project, my team had success using a package specific to Outlook for creating emails. Its called win32com.client. Has a number of options for manipulating Microsoft Office product files.

Comment: Could you expand this answer with a code example relevant to the question?